# Searching for Love

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Sometimes, in the course of searching for l o v e, you find that it has already surrounded you...

```
WWNQHAKUXSNMXXUCRSGG
ULLLTFLNVLIMCKXKSYIA
XLALYVPMBUZJYPCPGTEH
GLLLMJHGIDHBYFQGVVVC
UASGPMGSWVCLKYURVHVD
NIZVDTTONRABDHMXVVVK
IBZMVDCNYLGYMSOBIWIA
MTLXKCEEECSTCNAEOBMQ
LPMKRHETEIMEGSHFIYJN
IRWWAWEEEFRFDGFUIJUP
DTOZLDWCZYDKHXNSNNRU
BWGPPJWCHWYFKRROBUIA
CXJDVAEWNBAOIPUPMCSM
LXXOOOGRNFJSUUVZXTUQ
YYSOROBFKSYHNPCYAFGF
PIYOOOQABUYIEKFMAUXO
MFDTNMPGVUXEEEJSFVUS
ISVIOTIHKSUEEEKGTIGU
TEFLCNEDGPYEEEMQPVQK
NPDQEGHAUZMJWVCCSLAH
```

***Hint: Some unscrambling needed.**

Solve the puzzle, and you'll discover something that is related to love.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the answer lies in your

> HEART

since

> the grid of letters contains 3x3 blocks with eight L, O, V, E (twice) around the outside and letters A, R, H, T, E on the inside.

(Or perhaps that's just for fun and more unscrambling than this is needed to identify the *real* puzzle...)

Comment: I like loving earth more. Or a hater. :-)